# Simple component end up with hydration issues on Next 12

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm currently getting into Nextjs 12.2. I've a simple component that fetch data using `useSWR` but for some reasons, I got some hydration issues and can't understand where it is coming from. See bellow two examples, one failing and one working but I'd like to understand why the first one is not working.

---

End up with hydration issues

```js
import axios from "axios";
import useSWR from "swr";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";

const fetcher: any = (url: string) =>
  axios.get(url).then((response) => response.data);

function MyComponent() {
  const { data } = useSWR<[]>(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/articles", // Return an array of objects
    fetcher
  );

  return (
    <div className={styles["my-component"]}>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
          {data == undefined ? (
            <div>Loading...</div>
          ) : (
            data.map((a: any) => (
              <tr key={a.uid}>
                <td>{a.title}</td>
                <td>{a.description}</td>
              </tr>
            ))
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

---

End up working

```js
import axios from "axios";
import useSWR from "swr";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";

const fetcher: any = (url: string) =>
  axios.get(url).then((response) => response.data);

function MyComponent() {
  const { data } = useSWR<[]>(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/articles", // Return an array of objects
    fetcher
  );

  // Re-rendering the whole component instead of a part of the component seems to be issue, but why?
  if (!data) {
    return "loading...";
  }
  return (
    <div className={styles["my-component"]}>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
          {data == undefined ? (
            <div>Loading...</div>
          ) : (
            data.map((a: any) => (
              <tr key={a.uid}>
                <td>{a.title}</td>
                <td>{a.description}</td>
              </tr>
            ))
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

---

From what I understand, hydration is caused when the rendering of a component is different between SSR and first client rendering, but in the first example, I don't understand what's going wrong especially because it's a common use case to have only a part of your component to be conditionally rendered based on a fetch logic.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you check your console if there is any hydration error related to different class names?

Comment: yep, you are right, it was because a wrong HTML syntax. You can't render a div inside a table. Thank!s

Answer (score 0):

You can't render a `div` inside of a `table`, that was causing a `validateDOMNesting` error which will most likely trigger the hydration error.